# Scala set function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, set

In Stanford Scala course I've come across the following assignment:

**Exercise 1 – Sets as Functions:**

In this exercise we will represent sets as functions from Ints to Booleans:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

**a**) Write a function "set" that takes an Int parameter and returns a Set containing that Int.

**b**) Write a function "contains" that takes a Set and an Int as parameters and returns true if the Int is in the Set and false otherwise.

**c**) Write the functions "union", "intersect", and "minus" that take two Sets as parameters and return a Set.

**d**) Can you write a function "subset" which takes two Sets as parameters and returns true if the first is a subset of the second and false otherwise?

Solutions to the **a**, **b** and **c** are fairly trivial:

```
def set(i: Int): Set = n => n == i

def contains(s: Set, i: Int) = s(i)

def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = i => a(i) || b(i)

def intersect(a: Set, b: Set): Set = i => a(i) && b(i)

def minus(a: Set, b: Set): Set = i => a(i) && !b(i)
```

But is there any elegant solution for **d**?
Of course, strictly speaking, the answer to **d** is "yes", as I can write something like:

```
def subset(a: Set, b: Set) = Int.MinValue to Int.MaxValue filter(a) forall(b)
```

but that's probably not the right way.

Comment: I think that *is* the right way.

Comment: the course has nothing to do with Stanford

Comment: @Seth It was from Stanford's course, not current Coursera one even though the second assignment there is almost the same. Notice it didn't have -bound/bound tip, which btw answers my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without iterating through all the integers. For a pseudo-proof, look at the desired type:

```
def subset: (a: Set, b: Set): Boolean
```

Somehow, we've got to produce a `Boolean` when all we have to work with are sets (`a`, `b`) of type `Int => Boolean`, and integer equality `(Int, Int) => Boolean`. From these primitives, the only way to get a `Boolean` value is to start with `Int` values. Since we don't have any specific `Int`'s in our hands, the only option is to iterate through all of them.

If we had a magical oracle, `isEmpty: Set => Boolean`, the story would be different.

A final option is to *encode* "false" as the empty set and "true" as anything else, thus changing the desired type to:

```
def subset: (a: Set, b: Set): Set
```

With this encoding, logical "or" corresponds to the set union operation, but I don't know that logical "and" or "not" can be defined easily.

Answer (score 1):

We have

```
Set A = 
    Returns the intersection of the two given sets,
    the set of all elements that are both in `s` and `t`.

Set B = 
    Returns the subset of `s` for which `p` holds.
```

Isn't Set A is equivalent to Set B

```
def filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Set = intersect(s, p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kipton Barros, you would have to check all values for Ints since you want to prove that `forall x, a(x) implies b(x)`.

Regarding the optimization of it, I'd probably write:

```
  def subset(a: Set, b: Set) = Int.MinValue to Int.MaxValue exists(i => !a(i) || b(i))
```

since `!a(i) || b(i)` is equivalent to `a(i) implies b(i)`

Comment: From where do you get that function "exists"? Is it somewhere defined or did you leave it undefined?

Comment: The expression `Int.MinValue to Int.MaxValue` creates a Range type, which inherits from IterableLike, TraversableLike, TraversableOnce and finally from GenTraversableOnce, which is where the function `exists` is defined. Check out the docs at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range

Comment: Thanks, that day I seemed to be blind to see that it was a method call of that range.

Answer (score 0):

Later on in the Coursera exercises bounded sets are introduced and then forall() and exists() as universal and existential quantifiers over the bounds. subset() was not in the exercises but is similar to forall. Here is my version of subset():

```
// subset(s,p) tests if p is a subset of p returning true or false
def subset(s: Set, p: Set): Boolean = {
  def iter(a: Int): Boolean = {
    if (a > bound) { true
    } else if (contains(p, a)) {
        if (contains(s, a)) iter(a + 1) else false
    } else iter(a+1)
  }
  iter(-bound)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are two sets A and B, then A intersect B is a subset of A and B. Mathematically proven: `A ∩ B ⊆ A and A ∩ B ⊆ B`. Function can be written like this:

```
def filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Set = x => s(x) && p(x)
```

Or

```
def intersect(s: Set, t: Set): Set = x => s(x) && t(x)
def filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Set = intersect(s,p)
```

Comment: While the statement is correct, it doesn't provide and answer to the question.

Comment: @mins answer is given by Ronak. I just wanted to say that Intersection of two set is a subset of any of those two set. I am adding exact answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of it using contains function:

```
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = x => contains(s,x) || contains(t,x)

def intersect(s: Set, t: Set): Set = x => contains(s,x) && contains(t,x)

def diff(s: Set, t: Set): Set = x => contains(s,x) && !contains(t,x)

def filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Set = x =>  contains(s, x) && p(x)
```