# Unsure how this union function on Sets works

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to understand this def method :

```
def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = i => a(i) || b(i)
```

Which is referred to at question : [Scala set function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963792/scala-functional-set-problem)

This is my understanding :

The method takes two parameters of type Set - a & b
A Set is returned which the union of the two sets a & b.

Here is where I am particularly confused : Set = i => a(i) || b(i)

The returned Set itself contains the 'or' of Set a & b . Is the Set 'i' being populated by an implicit for loop ?

Since 'i' is a Set why is it possible to or a 'set of sets', is this something like whats being generated in the background :

```
a(i) || b(i) 
becomes
SetA(Set) || SetB(Set)
```

Comment: i is of type Int and a set can be seen as a predicate. Does this help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe what's confusing you is the syntax.  We can rewrite this as:

```
type Set = (Int => Boolean)

def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = {
  (i: Int) => a(i) || b(i)
}
```

So this might be easier to sort out.  We are defining a method `union` that takes to `Set`s and returns a new `Set`.  In our implementation, `Set` is just another name for a function from `Int` to `Boolean` (ie, a function telling us if the argument is "in the set").

The body of the the `union` method creates an anonymous function from `Int` to `Boolean` (which is a `Set` as we have defined it).  This anonymous function accepts a parameter `i`, an Int, and returns `true` if, and only if, `i` is in set `a` (`a(i)`) OR `i` is in set `b` (`b(i)`).

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully, that question defines a `type Set = Int => Boolean`. So we're not talking about `scala.collection.Set` here; we're talking `Int => Boolean`s.

To write a function literal, you use the `=>` keyword, e.g.

```
x => someOp(x)
```

You don't need to annotate the type if it's already known. So if we know that the r.h.s. is `Int => Boolean`, we know that `x` is type `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

No the set is not populated by a for loop.

The return type of `union(a: Set, b: Set): Set` is a function.  The code of the declaration `a(i) || b(i)` is not executed when you call `union`; it will only be executed when you call the result of `union`.

And `i` is not a set it is an integer.  It is the single argument of the function returned by `union`.

What happens here is that by using the `set` and `union` function you construct a binary tree of functions by combining them with the logical-or-operator (`||`).  The `set` function lets you build leafs and the `union` lets you combine them into bigger function trees.

Example:

```
def set_one = set(1)
def set_two = set(2)
def set_three = set(2)
def set_one_or_two = union(set_one, set_two)
def set_one_two_three = union(set_three, set_one_or_two)
```

The `set_one_two_three` will be a function tree which contains two nodes: the left is a function checking if the passed parameter is equal to 3; the right is a node that contains two functions itself, checking if the parameter is equal to 1 and 2 respectively.