# Union of two sets in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

From the question linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963792/scala-functional-set-problem), I found this implementation of Union in Scala:

```
def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = i => a(i) || b(i)
```

And Set is a function of type:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

Now I understand that in Scala, a function is mapped from Int to Boolean here, and I further understand how this statement is executed:

```
a(i) || b(i)
```

But what I don't understand is what is 'i' here. Where does it come from? And when it finds a match between to sets, it returns true, if it indeed does, where do I filter it?

Comment: It comes from the function. A set has an apply method, and it returns true if set contains an item, and false otherways. So union of two sets have an item, if at least one of them has it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let say we have object called `SoSet` given by

```
object SoSet {
    type Set = Int => Boolean
    val a : Set = ???
    val b : Set = ???
    def isItem(item : Int) = a(item) || b(item)
}
```

The signature of `isItem` is given by `Int => Boolean` which is a `Set`. So far so good.

But now we just want to *return the function* `isItem` (i.e. a `Set`).

So lets define `union` function for this (There are no parameters right now. We will add it later).

```
object SoSet {
    //..   
     def union : Set = isItem // returns the function isItem
}
```

Now lets refactor the `isItem` into a [anonymous function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html).

```
object SoSet {
    //..   
    def union : Set = {
      (item : Int) => a(item) || b(item)
    }
}
```

Lets move `Set a and b` from `object SoSet` to parameters of `def union`. Refactor `item` to `i`.

```
object SoSet { 
   type Set = Int => Boolean
   def union(a : Set, b : Set) : Set = (i : Int) => a(i) || b(i)
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
 val s1 = Set(1, 2, 3)                           
 val s2 = Set(2, 3, 4)     
 val s3 = union(s1, s2) //  returns the function..  Int => Boolean = <function1>
 s3(2)  // invokes the function & checks if 2 is present in the union
```

Comment: Great answer @Shrey. But I am a bit confused still. So if I call `union(s1, s2)`, then `i` goes over each element in both `a` and `b` implicitly to find union between them? I say implicitly because we don't define the value of `i` anywhere.

Comment: No.. `union(s1, s2)` will return a new `Set` which is itself a function. It won't go over to find the actual union until you invoke the returned function.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But what I don't seem to understand is `Set = (i : Int) => a(i) || b(i)` this statement. To be precise, if `s1(2,3,4)` and `s2(3,4,5)`, then `i` is the index of s1 and s2, and for each index `i`, the function is evaluated, and the result is returned, right?

Comment: No Dear.. `i` is the `item` (i.e. is the `element` of the Set). Not index.

Answer (score 18):

The `Set` (which is just a function) that gets returned from `union` takes some integer as a parameter; you must give it an arbitrary name so that you can refer to it in the function body. It may make more sense if you write the function like this:

```
def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = {
  (i) => a(i) || b(i)
}
```

It may make even more sense if you write it like this:

```
def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = {
  // The union of two sets is a new function that takes an Int...
  def theUnion(i: Int): Boolean = {
    // and returns true if EITEHR of the other functions are true
    a(i) || b(i)
  }

  // Now we want to return the NEW function
  theUnion
}
```

Again, `i` is arbitrary and could be replaced with any variable:

```
def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = item => a(item) || b(item)
```

**[Update]**

Because we're representing sets as *functions*, there's no need to iterate to see if they contain a number. For example, here's a set that contains any number below `-5`:

```
val belowNegFive: Set = (i) => i < -5
```

When we call that function with a number, it will tell us if that number is in the set. Note that at *no time* did we actually tell it the *specific numbers* that were in the set:

```
scala> belowNegFive(10)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> belowNegFive(-100)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> belowNegFive(-1)
res2: Boolean = false
```

Here's another set that includes any number between `50` and `100`:

```
val fiftyToHundred: Set = (i) => i >= 50 && i <= 100

scala> fiftyToHundred(50)
res3: Boolean = true

scala> fiftyToHundred(100)
res4: Boolean = true

scala> fiftyToHundred(75)
res5: Boolean = true

scala> fiftyToHundred(49)
res6: Boolean = false
```

Now, a *union* of the sets `belowNegFive` and `fiftyToHundred` would contain any number that is *either* below `-5` **or** between `50` and `100`. We can easily represent this in code by returning a *new* function which itself returns true if *either* of the other two functions returns true.

```
scala> val unionOfBoth: Set = (i) => belowNegFive(i) || fiftyToHundred(i)
unionOfBoth: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> unionOfBoth(-10)
res7: Boolean = true

scala> unionOfBoth(50)
res8: Boolean = true

scala> unionOfBoth(0)
res9: Boolean = false
```

The `union` function from your question is just a way of applying this pattern generically over *any* two sets.

Answer (score 1):

> And when it finds a match between to sets, it returns true, if it indeed does, where do I filter it?

`union` does not find a match between two sets, it creates a new set which contains the values of
both sets. Example:

```
val a = (i) => i == 2 // a contains 2 as a(2) == True
val b = (i) => i == 5 // b contains 5 as b(5) == True
val u = union(a, b)   // u contains 2 and 5 as u(2) == True and u(5) == True
```

So the 'filtering' just happens on the way. This function is not iterating over each set, filtering specific things out, it just returns a combination of two functions which then can executed later to query for the actual values.

Example of querying the values of a union:

```
val a = (i) => i == 2
val b = (i) => i == 5
val u = union(a, b)

for(i <- 1 to 10 if u(i)) yield i     // returns Vector(2, 5)
```

And yes, this is not an optimal way of storing values in sets as you have to check values by
guessing but it is a good way to demonstrate how combining functions adds complex functionality without
writing very complex code.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a union function like this:

```
def union[A](set1: Set[A], set2:Set[A]):Set[A] = {
    set1.foldLeft(set2)((set, elem) => set + elem)
}
```

or

```
def union[A](set1: Set[A], set2:Set[A]):Set[A] = {
    set1.flatMap(elem => set2 + elem)
}
```

These will be generic so you can use it for sets of any type