# scala iterating through the set type with condition

Tags: scala

I have a type of set and union function as follow

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)
val xs = Set(12001,12002, 12003, 12004)
val ys = Set(13001,13002, 13003, 13004)
```

When i use the union operation,

```
union(xs,ys)
```

It should return me another set which contains all the elements of both sets `xs` and `ys`

> Edited Section:

I am sorry i was not clear on my question, i have my own implementation of the iterator for both Set xs and ys

```
var i = xs.iterator;
while(i.hasNext)
  println(i.next())
```

But i was not satisfied with this implementation and found that you can implement the condition with the function (after some googling) but i was unable to get it to work in my eclipse worksheet.

```
val rs = union(xs,ys)            //> rs  : Learn2.Set = <function1>
```

I am guessing it returns a function.

so my questions,
1. is it possible to implement as described above in the edited section? if so, then what am i missing to get it working?
2. I don't understand how the element `e` in `(e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)` is iterating over the elements in both the sets

Comment: Your union function seems to work well. What would be your confusion?

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: Your proposition sounds right. :-)

Comment: I think the idea of doing a Coursera course is you do the work yourself. Or what's the point in taking the course?

Comment: @JeffHu sorr,y i was not clear updated my question

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov sorry, i was unclear. i updated the question

Comment: @stefanobaghino yea, but i was unsuccessful to get it to work.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul yes, you are right and i had my own implementation but I wanted to search and find if there is a better way of doing it (Basically  the new features Scala is packing). cheers :)

Comment: I found the solution to my answer here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204631/union-of-two-sets-in-scala

Answer (score 2):

Look at your `Set` type: `Int => Boolean`. So it takes an `Int` and returns a `Boolean`. What that means is that it is *not* a collection that you can iterate over to retrieve all its values, because it actually contains no values.

If you want to know what `Int` values return `true` then you have to iterate over the entire range of possible inputs (or some subset thereof) and filter for the condition you're looking for.

```
scala> val res = union(xs,ys)
res: Set = $$Lambda$1091/332405156@2c30c81d

scala> (0 to 20000).filter(res).foreach(println)
12001
12002
12003
12004
13001
13002
13003
13004

scala>
```

**update**

Your confusion stems from the fact that you've named your function after an existing collection in the standard library. `xs.itorator` works because `xs` is **not** an example of your `Set`, it is a `Set` from the standard library with all the associated methods. Rename your type alias to something like `Xet` and you'll see what I mean.

```
type Xet = Int => Boolean
def union(s: Xet, t: Xet): Xet = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)

val xx: Xet = _ == 12001
val yx: Xet = _ == 13002
val zx: Xet = union(xx, yx)

xx.itrerator // Error, won't compile
(1 to 20000).filter(zx).foreach(println) // output: 12001 & 13002
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for update.
I was able to iterate my set as follows, `var i = xs.iterator;
while(i.hasNext) println(i.next())` but i was not able to get the `union()` function to work. I have updated my question as i was not clear.

Comment: yes, you are right. I am new to this scala type let me do some digging and get back to you on this :)