# Any concise way to define a constant function (mapping) in scala

Tags: scala

I am a newbie in Scala. I have the following code to define a constant function that returns *true* for 1,2,3 and *false* for the other *Integers*.( actually the function defines [a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963792/scala-set-function) {1,2,3} of integers):

```
val a= Node1 _
def Node1(x:Int):Boolean={
            if (x==1 || x ==2 || x==3){true}
            else{false}
}
```

Is there any way to define this function more concisely?

Comment: `val a: Int => Boolean = Set(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: I case you can't use `Set`: `val test = (_: Int) match { case 1 | 2 | 3 => true; case _ => false }`

Comment: @Gábor Bakos How the code changes if I want to substitute *Int* with *Any*?

Comment: Mathematically, a *constant* function is a function that always returns the same value regardless of the argument. This is not the case for your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val a: Int => Boolean = Set(1, 2, 3).contains(_)
```

which is effectively same as

```
val a: Int => Boolean = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

This is because Set's `apply` method is same as its `contains` method.

Comment: The `.contains(_)` is superfluous.

Comment: Can you please give a hint how the code changes if I want to substitute Int with Any? Should I just replace Int with Any in the code?

Comment: Yes @qartal, val a: Any => Boolean = Set(1, 2, 3) works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

On lookup performance, although as aforementioned `Set.apply` conveys the desired semantics, note that `Set` is a trait that may implement for instance `ListSet`, `HashSet` or `TreeSet`, each designed for specific uses.

For the aim here of looking up for an element, consider `TreeSet` (see [Collections Performance Characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) for details) outperforms other `Set` implementations. This proves relevant specially for large collections.